# Reading text files with different parameters with spaces

Tags: c++

text file

690104014431    Tan Shou Ming   Male

730302027761    Andrew Tan  Male

### 880502066642    Sally Indera Ong    Female

```
ifstream theFile("PersonalInfo.txt");`

string n;
string i;
string g;
```

while( theFile >> i >> n >> g)

{
           cout << "Id: " << i << endl;``
            cout << "Name: " << n << endl;
            cout << "Gender: "<< g << endl;
}

The topmost part above is my text file I am trying to read into this programme. Since the names have spaces, parts of the names go into gender or id. May I know how can I solve this problem? The names have two to four spaces in between at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a simple pattern to match, you could use a [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex). e.g.

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "343545 john doe male";
    std::regex r(R"((\d+)\s+(.+)\s+(\w+))");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_match(s, m, r);
    std::cout << "Name: " << m[2].str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ID: " << m[1].str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Gender: " << m[3].str() << std::endl;
}
```

prints

```
Name: john doe
ID: 343545
Gender: male
```

Answer (score 0):

We introduce istringstream:

```
std::string line;
while(getline(theFile, line)){
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    std::string part;
    ss >> part;
    i = part;
    while(ss >> part){
        if(part != "Male" || part != "Female"){
           n += part;
        }else{
           g = part;
        }
}
```